# A question about the union of continuous images of X

Tags: general-topology

Let X,Y be two infinite Hausdorff spaces. Let $f:X→Y,g:X→Y$ be continuous functions. Is there a continuous function $h:X→Y$ such that $Im\,f∪Im\,g⊆Im\,h$?

I suspect that there is a counterexample, however I am slow at finding counterexamples.

Thank you

---

I just noticed that I forgot an important condition, which is that $Im\,f\cap Im\,g\not=\emptyset$. Damian Sobota already gave an answer to the easier question. I don't know if I should just accept the answer that I have and re ask my question with the new condition.

Comment: See my comment to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X=[0,1]$ and $Y=[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ with natural topologies. Let $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x+2$. As $Y$ is disconnected, there is no continuous function $h$ such that $\text{Im}f\cup\text{Im}g\subseteq\text{Im}h$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just noticed that I forgot a condition. I am sorry for this. +1

Comment: It's not a problem with your new condition. Just add one isolated point to my $X$ and $Y$ and map it properly.

Comment: Could you give the counter example explicitly

Comment: $X=[0,1]\cup\{4\}$ and $Y=[0,1]\cup[2,3]\cup\{4\}$, $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x+2$ for $x\neq 4$ and $g(4)=4$.

Comment: But now $X$ is disconnected

Comment: You want to argue that the number of connected components will increase ?

Comment: Yes. $h$ would still have to map $[0,1]$ to more than one component.